# Компиляция Python кода для 32-битной архитектуры из 64-битной

Tags: python

Я хочу поделиться игрой, которую я написал на python с другом, у которого не установлен python, как мне это сделать?
Мой компьютер: Windows 10, 64-bit.
Компьютер, на которых хочу отослать получившийся exe: Windows ?, 32-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно поставить питон 32 бит. Потом нужно поставить `Microsoft Build Tools 2015` и отметить там `Visual C++ 2008 32-bit`. Потом в пуске находишь Visual C++ 2008 32-bit Command Promt и на голом питоне устанавливаешь pyinstaller и нужные библиотеки через

```
c:/Python/Python3-32/python.exe -m pip install --no-binary :all: .....
```

Потом собирай экзешник в этой же коммандной строке.

Вместе с готовой программой положи vcredist https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26368 на случай если виндовс у друга без сервис пака

Comment: что делать, если 32-бит версия python-а устанавливается только до pip boostrap, дальше не идёт

Comment: У меня встало без проблем. Если не удастся запустить - пробуй `embeddable package`. но та вручную надо поставить setuptools и pip